# Send tab delimited txt values to PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a tab delimited txt file, where I would like to retrieve certain data off of each line, and place that data into an array.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$file_handle = fopen("/file.txt", "r");
$list = "";
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 0, "\t");
    $list .= $line_of_text[10] . " - " . $line_of_text[9] . ": " . $line_of_text[6];
}
fclose($file_handle);
```

I then want to put `$list` into an array like this `array($list)`. This array should then generate options in a select/dropdown menu on a form (the function to convert the array into options is already set, it's just a matter of getting the correct array output).

The problem is that when I access the form, all of the rows from the txt file are in one `<option>` in the select menu. So rather than having a select menu with a few dozen options, I'm getting a select menu with one option that contains a few dozen rows of data from the txt file.

Comment: Maybe: `$list[] = ...` instead of: `$list .= ...` ?!

Comment: you're not building an array. you're building a single long string. `.=` is string concatentation, not array_push. you want `$list[] = ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing `$list = ""` and using string append in your while (`$list .= ...`) you are creating one large string. If you want an array, then create an array, and [append to the array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php).

```
$file_handle = fopen("/file.txt", "r");
$list = array();
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 0, "\t");
    $list[] = $line_of_text[10] . " - " . $line_of_text[9] . ": " . $line_of_text[6];
}
fclose($file_handle);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Unfortunately my txt file is really large (78,000+ rows, so it's now exceeding the available memory to load the array in the menu.